# How best to determine with a sprite has been pushed off-screen?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, flappy-bird-clone

I'm developing a Flappy Bird clone (for learning purposes only!), but am a little confused when trying to detect when the bird has been pushed off-screen.

My plan was something akin to

```
if bird.position.x < 0 {
    // Bird is off screen, game over
}
```

However, this doesn't work as the bird (when hitting the left edge of the frame) seems to have a position.x of about (but not exactly) 270.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @0x141E this sorts out the boundaries correctly - thank you - but seems to screw up the sprite positioning. With an X co-ord of 358, the bird is almost touching the right hand edge. How should I adjust the position settings with .ResizeFill set?

Comment: Doesn't position.x and position.y refer to the center of the sprite in SpriteKit by default (assuming you didn't change the anchor center) ? So maybe you need `bird.position.x + (bird.size.width / 2.0)` to ensure the entire bird node is really off screen ?